# Using a custom sbt plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I've created a new scala project and written an `AutoPlugin` underneath it in a `src/main/scala/com/company/plugin` directory and a corresponding namespace.  The plugin code is a cut and paste of `HelloPlugin3` from [1], however I have changed the names.

Then, in a second sbt project I've updated the `project/plugins.sbt` file to include my new Hello World plugin.  This second project has other 'business code' in.  When I run sbt in that second project, the plugin is resolved and I've tested that by deleting the jar from underneath the `~/.ivy/local/...` and then reloading the project and witnessing sbt complain that it can't find the plugin.  When I `publishLocal` my plugin project again, that error goes away.

So I'm happy that the plugin is resolved and the jar file is not empty because I have checked its contents.

However, when I do an `sbt> about` my custom plugin isn't listed and the command I was expecting to be available isn't.  ("[error] Not a valid command: hello").  But the other plugin I list in plugins.sbt (io.spray sbt-revolver) does appear in the output.

Both the plugin project and the second project have `scalaVersion  := "2.10.3"` specified in their `build.sbt` files.

I'm using sbt 0.13.6.  Interestingly, and perhaps related, is the sbt command `plugins` is not apparently valid in this project either, although it works just fine in the plugin project.

What extra step am I missing to make the command available to my second project?  How do I check to see if I've got some particularly messed up sbt config happening?

For convenience, the plugin code is below, but as mentioned, it's a copy from the link underneath it.

```
package com.company.plugin

import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val greeting = settingKey[String]("greeting")
  }

  import autoImport._
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    greeting := "Hi",
    commands += helloCommand)
  lazy val helloCommand = 
    Command.command("hello") { (state: State) =>
      println("fred")
      state
    }   

}
```

Edit:

The `build.sbt` for the plugin project as as follows;

```
sbtPlugin := true

scalaVersion  := "2.10.3"

organization  := "com.company"

name    := "name"

version   := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

The only other file I've created in this project is the `.scala` file for the plugin itself.

[1] http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins.html

Comment: In the sbt config of the project where the plugin is defined, did you specify that it is a sbt plugin with `sbtPlugin := true` ??

Comment: Yes, I have.  I've edited the question and given the whole `build.sbt` for the plugin project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the `project/build.properties` of the project trying to use the plugin.  This file set the sbt version to `0.13.1`, which for some reason cases both my plugin and the sbt `plugins` command to not work.

Changing the value to `0.13.6` made all the problems go away.